# Trying to retrieve a userCertificate from Windows Active directory using java CertStore but no success

Tags: java, active-directory, openldap

I am trying to retrive a userCertificate associated with a domain name from Windows Active Directory but having difficulties by using Java API

for example when I use 'ldapsearch' command tool, I am able to retrieve the certificate as you can see below

```
ldapsearch -h 192.xx.2.xx  -D "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=mmo,DC=co,DC=ca" -w Password -b "CN=rsa0,CN=Users,DC=mmo,DC=co,DC=ca" "userCertificate"

# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <CN=rsa0,CN=Users,DC=mmo,DC=co,DC=ca> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: userCertificate 
#

# rsa0, Users, mmo.co.ca
dn: CN=rsa0,CN=Users,DC=mmo,DC=co,DC=ca
userCertificate:: MIIDbTCCAlWgAwIBAgIEFbvHazANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBnMQswCQYDVQQG
 EwJ1azEQMA4GA1UECBMHVW5rbm93bjEWMBQGA1UEBxMNcmlja21hbnN3b3J0aDERMA8GA1UEChMId
 m9jYWxpbmsxDDAKBgNVBAsTA2lwczENMAsGA1UEAxMEcnNhMDAeFw0xOTExMjExNDUwNDNaFw0yOT
 ExMTgxNDUwNDNaMGcxCzAJBgNVBAYTAnVrMRAwDgYDVQQIEwdVbmtub3duMRYwFAYDVQQHEw1yaWN
 rbWFuc3dvcnRoMREwDwYDVQQKEwh2b2NhbGluazEMMAoGA1UECxMDaXBzMQ0wCwYDVQQDEwRyc2Ew
 MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA0R0yCr0uU80oFG3Zg0vTbR4NSR2St+w4f
 DOmoHQ27z1Q2JwhiNh1XkwC8MtVeGzRJw0pe+jXc2fMVbIqONHImOZuX6p1UMWof7fxMAIEfWq98u
 OqVbvbXVLeCE9+BJGsOaiJ70Q76e8tDNTH3vg1orXAvb0O7R0Vz9I0iXjJKzUtmFEBju/m3eoa+WI
 6OaBr64hJw7oz1CzPIKj0OcapFypFjr4+QKpRsHA4Nn21XrYSsT00Dk9SVK3NTjHm661crvTR6jSx
 j1GrCpVdQGCQ25a2RrHIi0cmclNJmy81PngW0cpdO3p9ZsZ2vPUy5/CNbVwqPEPSlIjJtVa0Xf9O1
 QIDAQABoyEwHzAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU1U7VOM/vAHL0pqZgi6TS1f0SAt8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADgg
 EBAC7fK81BHDbF8PSQO2YznZtnzCMs46TwCezyqIFzQljwYA5wxKIytV7GtV4aEUrfIFIeQIMW812
 pMol9xIotULSl1I/2WI18QTIJfRAnkCZZPJIa9MU6nEGCouF1LwW9bzQzHOeI07NgCIyBryojXaxc
 L/epJtVxYialdI9mBWB8KDytINrylOcP9sXYaUtkOOiU7h0sBF9XBfzXgtTkF8pB7ObX9YJnyvzTn
 y2zVfeZD8Q7BtDL7AvIDcUjoHtYx5B0oD86aCNTSShmtB/ZEyqt8Kynqf+QUYQIWA3wVFjgZjCCwc
 NxiXuf6H8KGW8hP+ETKnc7u9XP9GCHINf9K0I=

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

however when I try to use the Java program, I am unable to retrive it, below is the sample java program

```
package CertStore;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import java.security.cert.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class CertStoreTest {
    CertStoreTest() {
        try {
            LDAPCertStoreParameters lcsp =
                    new LDAPCertStoreParameters("192.xx.2.xx", 389);

            String referenceID = "CN=rsa0,CN=Users,DC=bmo,DC=co,DC=ca";

            X509CertSelector xcs = new X509CertSelector();
            xcs.setSubject(referenceID);

            CertStore cs = CertStore.getInstance("LDAP", lcsp);

            Collection certificates = cs.getCertificates((CertSelector)xcs);

            System.out.println("size: "+ certificates.size());
            Iterator certificate = certificates.iterator();

            while(certificate.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(certificate.next());
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main() called.");
        CertStoreTest test = new CertStoreTest();
    }
}
```

When I run this program, I get the size as 0 where I am expecting as 1.

main() called.
size: 0

I also have openldap running on a linux system, and in the above java program if I point to that server and with appropriate domain name information, java is able to pull the certificate associated with that domain name.

Not sure what I am missing when I try to  retrive certificate from Windows Active Directory.

Can anyone shed some light on this as I have been stuck for few days now.

Comment: My blind guess would be that you need to authenticate yourself to read anything from Active Directory and the above code does not seem to use any credentials to read the LDAP.

Comment: If you want to connect to windows AD without binding (or binding anonymously ) we need to change the below property in the Windows AD. I have did that already
1. Start Adsiedit.msc (Start, Run, Adsiedit.msc).
2. Expand the Configuration container. Expand Services, Windows NT.
3. Right-click CN=Directory Service and select Properties.
4. Double-click the dSHeuristics attribute.
5. If the value is currently <Not Set>, set it to 0000002. If it isn't currently blank, you must change the 7th character of the string to 2. (For example, if it was 001, 0010002 should be your new value. Click OK.